# PDF file not opening using Android:OnClick

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent

So I've managed to get a button to open a pdf file using an intent, however when i run the app and press the button it says "Cannot display PDF". Can anyone help me out as to where exactly the code goes wrong?

Here is the my activity:

```
package com.example.android.practiceapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;

public class promotions extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_promotions);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.earlybird);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/pictures/Early_Bird_Bonus_Rules");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                Intent intent1 = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open With");
                try {
                    startActivity(intent1);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
                }
            }

        });

 }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some additional details, for example; The file are you trying to open itself. Have you tried on multiple versions of Android? One thing I can imagine in your current code is that the app trying to open the pdf breaks because the file you are trying to open appears to not have the .pdf extension

Comment: Have you add runtime permission for accessing files from external storage. That might be a reason.

Comment: @Thys - I've only tried my own device which is lollipop. And also, you're saying I should change the name to "Early_Bird_Bonus_Rules.pdf"?

Comment: @Pallavi I have the permissions in my androidmanifest.xml

Comment: File extension is part of the file's name and thus part of the path.

Comment: changed it, still didn't work.